# Макс и числа без 11

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можете помочь ускорить или переписать код?

- ограничение по времени на тест: 2 секунды
- ограничение по памяти на тест: 64 мегабайта
- ввод: стандартный ввод
- вывод: стандартный вывод

Макс сконструировал очередное электронное устройство. Оно должно было показывать двоичные числа:

1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111, 1000, . . .
Но что-то пошло не так. По какой-то причине устройство оказалось неспособно отображать две единицы подряд, поэтому оно пропускает числа, в записи которых содержится 11:

1, 10, 100, 101, 1000, 1001, 1010, . . .
Помогите Максу определить, какое число устройство покажет
N-м по счёту.

**Входные данные**:
Ввод содержит целое число N (1≤N≤10^9).

**Выходные данные**:
Выведите N-е в порядке возрастания двоичное число, не содержащее двух единиц подряд.

Примеры:

входные данные: 3

выходные данные: 100

входные данные: 140

выходные данные: 1010100101

```
a=int(input())
i=0
d=0
while d != a:
    i += 1
    d+=int(not "11" in bin(i))
    if d == a:
        print(bin(i)[2:])
```

Comment: Возможно переписывание на паскаль с указанием версии))

Comment: Наивно думать что за две секунды можно перебрать и проанализировать миллиард чисел. Тут нужен двоичный поиск и немного хитрости.

Comment: А если по точнее?

Comment: Если будет время, сегодня ночью напишу. А вы пока подумайте как можно сосчитать сколько таких чисел, скажем, из 10 двоичных цифр. Это не сложно и прикольно.

Comment: Спасибо, подумаю.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, тут нужен не бинпоиск, а динамическое программирование. Хотя, есть вероятность, что надо всё же обернуть в бинпоиск. А перебрать 10**9 чисел за 2 секунды более-менее возможно на некоторых языках, если нет сложной обработки. Даже на js занимает 3.2s: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWY7y.png. На Си++ получилось меньше секунды, но я не знаю, что он там пооптимизировал: https://ideone.com/craJHy.

Comment: Хм.. А это не троичная система счисления случайно? Хотя, наверное, нет.

Comment: Современный компьютер исполняет около трёх миллиардов инструкций ассемблера в секунду. Отсюда моя оценка о том что **с анализом** в две секунды не уложиться даже на C++. Про динамическое программирование вы правы, я не хотел спугнуть ТС такими словами. Тут такие маленькие числа что можно и без ДП уложится в нужное время.

Comment: Ради интереса попробовал перебор оптимизировать через `numba.njit`, в общем, уже поиск миллионного числа получается 3 секунды, так что перебором без шансов, только математика и закономерности. )

Answer (score 7):

Вывел все подобные числа до 1000:

```
for k in range(1, 1000):
    if not '11' in str(bin(k)):
        print(str(bin(k))[2:])
```

Попробовал найти закономерность:

```
1

10

100
101

1000
1001
1010

10000
10001
10010
10100
10101

100000
100001
100010
100100
100101
101000
101001
101010

1000000
1000001
1000010
1000100
1000101
1001000
1001001
1001010
1010000
1010001
1010010
1010100
1010101

10000000
10000001
10000010
10000100
10000101
10001000
10001001
10001010
10010000
10010001
10010010
10010100
10010101
10100000
10100001
10100010
10100100
10100101
10101000
10101001
10101010

100000000
100000001
100000010
100000100
100000101
100001000
100001001
100001010
100010000
100010001
100010010
100010100
100010101
100100000
100100001
100100010
100100100
100100101
100101000
100101001
100101010
101000000
101000001
101000010
101000100
101000101
101001000
101001001
101001010
101010000
101010001
101010010
101010100
101010101
```

Количество чисел в каждой "группе": `1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21`... ничего не напоминает?:)

Причем, внутри каждого блока если отбросить первые две цифры, оставшиеся числа будут точно совпадать со всеми числами до предыдущей группы. Получается фибоначчи внутри фибоначчи.

Во-первых, числа фибоначчи довольно быстро растут. 45-е число переходит за миллиард (максимальное N по условию задачи). Поэтому можно заранее собрать первые 45 чисел в список.

Во-вторых, т.к. "группы" чисел выше разбиты по количеству цифр, получив `N`, можно пройтись по списку чисел фибоначчи и точно узнать, в какой по счету группе находится искомое число (а значит, и количество её цифр).

Решение нашлось интуитивно (и внезапно, прошло все тесты).

В задаче есть пример `140` → `1010100101`. Магия такая:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ...] (отбросил двойные единички)
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  11, ...)

140 >= 89  (10-е число); 140 -= 89 → 51
 51 >= 34  ( 8-е число);  51 -= 34 → 17
 17 >= 13  ( 6-е число);  17 -= 13 → 4
  4 >= 3   ( 3-е число);   4 -= 3  → 1
  1 >= 1   ( 1-е число);   1 -= 1  → 0
_______________________________________
            1010100101
           10 8 6  3 1
```

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = L = [1, 1]

    for k in range(n - 2):
        a, b = b, a + b
        L.append(b)

    return L

fib_list = fib(45)
fib_list[0] = 0 # две единицы вначале мешают.
fib_rvrs = list(reversed(fib_list))

def bubu(N):
    ones = [] # Будет собирать позиции единичек в числе

    while N > 0:
        for f in fib_rvrs:
            if N >= f:
                max_fib = f
                break

        N -= max_fib
        ones.append(fib_list.index(max_fib))

    # ones = [9, 7, 5, 3] -> 101010100
    #                        9 7 5 3
    result = ''
    ones += [0]

    for i in range(len(ones) - 1):
        result += '1'
        result += '0' * (ones[i] - ones[i + 1] - 1)

    return result


N = int(input())
print( bubu(N) )
```

Миллиардное число: `1010000100100001010101000001000101000101001`

Ура!

Answer (score 3):

Отличный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1274831/416121) [OPTIMUS PRIME](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/310962/optimus-prime) объясняет как получить решение. Добавлю только две вещи.

Задача свелась к разложению числа по числам Фибоначчи. Вы скорее всего знакомы с разложением по степеням десятки и двойки. Скажем разложение числа 140 по степеням двойки имеет вид:

```
10001100b =
= 1 * 2^7 + 0 * 2^6 + 0 * 2^5 + 0 * 2^4 + 1 * 2^3 + 1 * 2^2 + 0 * 2^1 + 0 * 2^0 =
= 128 + 8 + 4 =
= 140
```

Разложение по числам Фибоначчи:

```
1010100101fib =
= 1 * fib(11) + 0 * fib(10) + 1 * fib(9) + 0 * fib(8) + 1 * fib(7) +
+ 0 * fib(6) + 0 * fib(5) + 1 * fib(4) + 0 * fib(3) + 1 * fib(2) =
= 89 + 34 + 13 + 3 + 1 = 
= 140
```

При разложении числа алгоритм один и тот-же для степеней двойки и для чисел Фибоначчи. Из разлагаемого числа последовательно вычитаем числа из ряда (степеней или Фибоначчи). Когда вычесть удаётся записываем единицу, иначе ноль:

```
140
 i   2^i   n - 2^i      бит  : fib(i+2) n - fib(i+2)  бит
 9:  512                     :    89    140 - 89 = 51  1
 8:  256                     :    55                   0
 7:  128 140 - 128 = 12  1   :    34     51 - 34 = 17  1
 6:   64                 0   :    21                   0
 5:   32                 0   :    13     17 - 13 =  4  1
 4:   16                 0   :     8                   0
 3:    8  12 -   8 =  4  1   :     5                   0
 2:    4   4 -   4 =  0  1   :     3      4 -  3 =  1  1
 1:    2                 0   :     2                   0
 0:    1                 0   :     1      1 -  1 =  0  1
```

Программа разлагающая число по ряду Фибоначчи:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(None)
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


def bits(n):
    k = 0
    while fib(k) <= n:
        k += 1

    for i in reversed(range(2, k)):
        if fib(i) <= n:
            yield '1'
            n -= fib(i)
        else:
            yield '0'


print(*bits(int(input())), sep='')
```

> ```
> $ echo 3 | python fib_bin.py 
> 100
>
> $ echo 140 | python fib_bin.py 
> 1010100101
>
> $ echo 1000000000 | python fib_bin.py 
> 1010000100100001010101000001000101000101001
> ```